# error: breqn.sty and algorithm2e.sty not found

Tags: algorithm2e, breqn

I've installed MikTex 2.9 for Windows 7, 64 bit. While trying to compile my Tex, I receive the following errors:

LaTeX Error: File `breqn.sty' not found.
LaTeX Error: File`algorithm2e.sty' not found.

I'm using these two packages in my code:

```
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[boxed,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Seems that you do not have installed these packages. Although I'm using Mac OS, I think you could use [MiKTeX Package Manager](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html), if installed, to check proper installation of needed packages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! If you made a basic install, these packages aren't installed by default. Install them with `MiKTeX Package Manager`.

Comment: Thank you. I added algorithm2e but breqn.sty is not in the list.

Answer (score 2):

The `breqn` package was recently dissociated from `mathtools`. To see it, you should synchronize the list of files in the package repositories. To do so, launch MiKTeX Package Manager, click on the `Repository` menu and select `Synchronize`:

[image]

Comment: I followed your instructions. When installing breqn I got "Windows API error87: The parameter is incorrect.", Data:C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\be48a8a88e3570f31e8be8fd4a43a2fd.fndb

Comment: Wasn't the compiler still working or complaining? Try closing your editor first.